# Windows install missing NTLDR

Tags: windows-xp, installation, bootloader, ntldr

I'm having trouble install WinXP Pro on my pc because NTLDR is missing or can't find during installation process. I highly doubt it's my DVD drive because this machine work fine before the install process. The DVD rom work.

Is there a work around for this problem?

edit: this is the [problem](http://www.techimo.com/forum/technical-support/125442-can-not-find-ntldr-please-insert-another-disk-help.html) that i'm having. I'm trying to reformat the hard disk with killdisk.

Comment: Does the missing NTLDR occur as the DVD is first starting up, or upon the 2nd reboot as XP is installing?

Comment: @Mike, the problem occur during install process. It said it can't find the NTLDR from the CD drive.

Answer (score 2):

Reboot with the install disk and do the following:

When you see the *Welcome to Setup* blue screen.

```
Press R
<Your screen will go black>
Press "1"
<Enter your admin password>
<At the prompt type this, where D is your dvd rom>
COPY D:\i386\NTLDR C:
COPY D:\i386\NTDETECT.COM C:
FIXBOOT
<Press Y>
<Then reboot>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple harddrives, try installing with only one hdd plugged in as Windows some times has problems booting from secondary drives.